# Apache SSL configuration testing

Tags: ssl, redhat, apache-1.3

When I run configtest on our Apache server, I get the following:

```
`Syntax error on line 1023 of /www/conf/httpd.conf: 
Invalid command 'SSLEnable', perhaps mis-spelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`
```

I know this part of the configuration works. Is there a trick to make configtest mod_ssl aware?

EDIT: 
RHEL4, nonstandard Apache 1.3 install? I just wanted to fix the ssl access log format to where Webalizer can give a clearer picture on who's still using this thing before we take the thing down. Since it's going away, no point upgrading apache just for this side project.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error when mod_ssl is not loaded, because of this Apache doesn't know about the `SSLEnable` configuration directive. Make sure mod_ssl is installed and enabled in your configuration, you can get a list of modules by running `httpd -M`. If ssl_module is not listed you can install mod_ssl by running `yum install mod_ssl` (assuming RedHat EL is using `yum` as a package manager like CentOS).

Comment: With Apache 1.3 `-M` doesn't exist.  You can still run `-l` to list compiled-in modules.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have mod_ssl installed and operational with the configuration but still receive an error when running configtest.

Are you using the `apachectl` appropriate to your installation?  If you have a package installed and it compiled from source as well, you may be running apachectl with a binary that isn't mod_ssl aware.